# The url() is not resolved properly when using style-loader and css-loader

Tags: javascript, css, webpack

I'm using webpack with style-loader, css-loader and file-loader. When my CSS is extracted into a separate CSS file, the urls are all converted as below.

background-image: url([object Object]);
.........
content: url([object Object]);

My webpack.js file is as given below,

```
plugins: [ new ExtractTextPlugin("styles_[hash].css") ],
module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        fallback: "style-loader",
        use: "css-loader"
      })
    },


        {
          test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|cur)$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'file-loader',
              options: {
                  name : '[name]_[hash].[ext]',
                  useRelativePath : true
              }
            }
          ]
        },

          // All files with a '.ts' or '.tsx' extension will be handled by 'awesome-typescript-loader'.
          { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "awesome-typescript-loader"},

          // All output '.js' files will have any sourcemaps re-processed by 'source-map-loader'.
          { enforce: "pre", test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader" }
      ]
},
```

I'm using ExtractTextWebpackPlugin and passing it to the plugins array

Comment: Refer to this section in [WebPack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/#loading-css) site

Comment: @sai: What is the actual URL you are passing in Source File?
background-image: url([object Object]); ......... content: url([object Object]);